# How to run a thread alongside telethon client

Tags: python-3.x, telethon

I'm willing to send some messages using [telethon](https://github.com/LonamiWebs/Telethon) based on time, my approach was to write a function and start it in a new thread and check what messages I have to send each second. i.e. something like below:

```
async def function():
  while True:
    time = datetime.datetime.now()
    await send_some_messages(time)
```

but telethon needs me to await on the same loop as it is running. I know that I can get the current loop with `client.run_until_disconnected()`, but I'm confused how can I do this.

It'd be great if you could give me an approach to run this function in a different thread, but still be able to send messages using the telethon client.

Comment: Why would you like to run it in a thread?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You don't need to use threads when you're working with [`asyncio`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio.html), and you also don't have to use [`client.run_until_disconnected()`](https://docs.telethon.dev/en/latest/modules/client.html#telethon.client.updates.UpdateMethods.run_until_disconnected). All that does is keep the event loop running until the client is disconnected. As long as you run the event loop, Telethon will work just fine.

```py
# Create client
client = ...

# Do whatever with the client
@client.on(...)
async def handler(event):
    ...

async def main():
    while True:
        # Do whatever (check if now is time to send messages, for example)
        ...

        # Yielding control back to the event loop here (with `await`) is key.
        # We're giving an entire second to it to do anything it needs like
        # handling updates, performing I/O, etc.
        await asyncio.sleep(1)

client.loop.run_until_complete(main())
```

Other ways to keep the event loop running are using [`loop.run_forever`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html#asyncio.loop.run_forever), and don't forget you can [`asyncio.create_task`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.create_task) or wait on many of them… I encourage you to read the `asyncio` docs. Just like `threading`, the documentation is worth checking out to learn how to use it.

---

As a side note, if you *really* need threads (for example, you're doing CPU intensive work), `asyncio` also has your back covered. But none of this is really specific to Telethon.

If you want to get a better understanding on how `asyncio` works (maybe that helps you) see [An Introduction to Asyncio](https://lonami.dev/blog/asyncio/)

Needless to say, there are better ways to check when it's time to send messages (using a heap and events, sleeping until the next time is due or another maximum and not just one second), but this should get you started.

Comment: For CPU intensive work you should use a separate process rather than a thread, at least in CPython (the Python implementation from `python.org`). In CPython, only *one thread at a time* can be executing Python bytecode.

Comment: @RolandSmith well, yes. But really I meant anything blocking for a non-trivial amount of time should be put in, at least, a thread, which is generally easier and more lightweight than an entire process. This will still let `asyncio` run and not block the entire event loop.

Comment: Is there any way to modify the code such that event handler for new incoming messages will still execute even the script was running the Do whatever part of the while loop? I noticed that if the script was executing the Do whatever part, all messages that are received at the moment will not be handled.

Comment: As long as you're yielding control to the event loop often enough, you should still receive messages. Maybe you want [`loop.run_in_executor`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html#asyncio.loop.run_in_executor) though, to put intensive things in another thread.

Answer (score 2):

[client.run_until_disconnected() blocks!](https://docs.telethon.dev/en/stable/concepts/asyncio.html#client-run-until-disconnected-blocks)

If you need both the `handler` and the `main` function to work, do something like this:

```py
# Get event loop
loop = asyncio.get_event_loop() 

# Create client
client = TelegramClient(..., loop=loop)
client.start()

# Do whatever with the client
@client.on(...)
async def handler(event):
    ...

async def main():
    while True:
        # Do whatever (check if now is time to send messages, for example)
        ...

        # Yielding control back to the event loop here (with `await`) is key.
        # We're giving an entire second to it to do anything it needs like
        # handling updates, performing I/O, etc.
        await asyncio.sleep(1)

loop.create_task(main())

client.run_until_disconnected()
loop.close()
```